# Why is DH20 not correctly negotiated with remote host when establishing an IPSec tunnel?

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

Trying to connect a computer to a VPN server configured this way :

```
Router# show isakmp policy
ISAKMP policy: L2TP_VPN
  IKD_ID: 8
  negotiation mode: main
  proposal: 1
    encryption: aes256
    authentication: sha256
  proposal: 2
    encryption: aes256
    authentication: sha512
  SA lifetime: 86400
  key group: group20
  NAT traversal: yes
  dead peer detection: yes
  my address: wan1
    type: interface
  secure gateway address: 1
    address: 0.0.0.0
  secure gateway address: 2
    address: 0.0.0.0
  fall back: deactivate
  fall back check interval: 300
  authentication method: pre-share
  pre-shared key: PRESHAREDKEYHERE
  certificate: default
  local ID: 0.0.0.0
    type: ip
  peer ID: 
    type: any
  user ID: 
  type: 
  X-Auth: no
    type: server
    method: default
    allowed user: Utilisateurs_VPN
    username: 
    password: 
  EAP-Auth: no
    type: 
    aaa method: 
    allowed user: 
    allowed auth method: mschapv2
    username: 
    auth method: mschapv2
    password: 
  vcp reference count: 0
  IKE_version: IKEv1
  active: yes
```

The phase 2 part

```
Router> show crypto map VPN_CONNECTION1
cryptography mapping: VPN_CONNECTION1
  VPN gateway: L2TP_VPN
  Gateway IP Version: IPv4
  encapsulation: transport
  active protocol: esp
  transform set: 1
    encryption: aes256
    authentication: sha512
  transform set: 2
    encryption: aes256
    authentication: sha256
  SA lifetime: 28800
  PFS: group15
  nail up: no
  scenario: remote-access-server
  l2tp: yes
  local policy: L2TP_VPN_LOCAL
  remote policy: any
  protocol type: any
  configuration provide:   
    mode config: no
    configuration payload: no
    address pool: 
    first dns: 
    second dns: 
    first wins: 
    second wins: 
  policy enforcement: no
  replay detection: no
  narrowed: yes
  adjust mss: yes
  mss value: 0
  stop rekeying: no
  NetBIOS broadcast over IPSec: no
  outbound SNAT: no
    source: 
    destination: 
    target: 
  inbound SNAT: no
    source: 
    destination: 
    target: 
  inbound DNAT: no
  vcp reference count: 0
  active: yes
  VTI: 
  VPN ID: 2
  connected: no
  connectivity check: no
    check method: none
    IP address: none
    period: none
    timeout: none
    fail tolerance: none
    port: none
    log: no
  rule type: 4in4
```

L2TP part :

```
Router# show l2tp-over-ipsec ;
L2TP over IPSec:
  activate          : yes
  crypto            : VPN_CONNECTION1
  address pool      : L2TP_VPN_IP_ADDRESS_POOL
  authentication    : default
  certificate       : default
  user              : Utilisateurs_VPN
  keepalive timer   : 60
  first dns server  : 
  second dns server : 
  first wins server : 
  second wins server:
```

This is how ike-scan sees the server :

```
Zulgrib@computer:~$ sudo ./ike-scan.sh GATEWAYIP | grep SA=
    SA=(Enc=AES Hash=SHA2-512 Auth=PSK Group=21 KeyLength=256 LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
```

I configured the client using NetworkManager.

```
[connection]
id=MyVpnName
uuid=3a6d0094-ff3e-49a2-95a3-54303542b2da
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=user:Zulgrib:;
timestamp=1605784830

[vpn]
gateway=GATEWAYIP
ipsec-enabled=yes
ipsec-esp=aes256-sha256-ecp384
ipsec-ike=aes256-sha256-ecp384
ipsec-psk=PRESHAREDKEY
password-flags=1
user=testvpn
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

But router side, logs claim the VPN client tried to use AES128 and modp3072 instead.

```
Recv:[SA][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID]
Recv IKE sa: SA([0] protocol = IKE (1), AES CBC key len = 256, HMAC-SHA256 PRF, HMAC-SHA256-128, 384 bit ECP, AES CBC key len = 128, 3072 bit MODP; ).
The cookie pair is : 0xhexhexhex / 0xhexhexhex [count=2]
Send:[SA][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID][VID]
Recv:[NOTIFY:INVALID_KEY_INFORMATION]
```

Client side, there is an error while negotiating too :

```
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA 3a6d0094-ff3e-49a2-95a3-54303542b2da[1] to GATEWAYIP
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: sending packet: from 192.168.170.52[500] to GATEWAYIP[500] (216 bytes)
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received packet: from GATEWAYIP[500] to 192.168.170.52[500] (410 bytes)
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V V V V ]
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received unknown vendor ID: f7:58:f2:26:68:75:0f:03:b0:8d:f6:eb:e1:d0:04:03
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02 vendor ID
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03 vendor ID
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received XAuth vendor ID
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received DPD vendor ID
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received unknown vendor ID: af:ca:d7:13:68:a1:f1:c9:6b:86:96:fc:77:57
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received unknown vendor ID: f9:19:6d:f8:6b:81:2f:b0:f6:80:26:d8:87:6d:cb:7b:00:04:32:00
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received unknown vendor ID: ac:40:f8:c4:38:99:27:c6:e8:ac:24:53:1b:b7:8b:2b:27:fc:b5:21:73:53:c1:94:4a:02:92:52:ac:c9:ab:03:8e:fa:5c:a1:d1:c6:24:15:c3:df:8e:e1:58:61:fa:ea:48:80:9d:c2:a6:c4:b
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: received unknown vendor ID: b6:c9:8c:ca:29:0a:eb:be:37:f1:9f:31:12:d2:d7:cb
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: negotiated DH group not supported
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1203248937 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: sending packet: from 192.168.170.52[500] to GATEWAYIP[500] (56 bytes)
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: establishing connection '3a6d0094-ff3e-49a2-95a3-54303542b2da' failed
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer charon[30591]: 12[IKE] negotiated DH group not supported
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer charon[30591]: 12[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1203248937 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer charon[30591]: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.170.52[500] to GATEWAYIP[500] (56 bytes)
nov. 19 17:28:16 computer NetworkManager[1337]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
```

How do I configure NetworkManager to use ecp384 (DH20) and not modp3072 (DH15), plus AES256 in all phases ?

Router side configuration cannot be changed, because it is currently the strongest configuration that are (supposedly) supported by both strongswan (used by network manager) and Win10 IPSec client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out OpenSSL is mandatory for ecp384 to work.
By default, Canonical package for libstrongswan does not use OpenSSL, it require package libstrongswan-standard-plugins for that.